Не работает пакетный менеджер dnf в федора 41
Недавно перешёл с 11 винды на fedora 41. Хотел установить гит, написал команду dnf install git терминал говорит что команда днф не найдена. пробовал установить днф через команду yum но толку было ноль. Как это исправить?
